# Confluent Kafka : Operator Based Installation stuck in KSQL, Schema Registry, Control Center, Replicator

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, kubernetes-operator

When I tried to set up the Kafka cluster based on the Kafka operator based installation is not getting succeed and stuck in KSQL, Schema Registry, Control Center, Replicator installation . But not giving any error also . [image]